# Unknown API function: "files/upload

Tags: http, dropbox

I Am New TO dropbox api  Today i tried to upload a file from https api  but got error while uploading the file

Unknown API function: "files/upload

My code is

function main()
    local oHTTP,cJSON,url
    setmode(25,80)

```
ctoken      :=     "<REDACTED>"

* //  cJSON = {"path": "hb_cwd()+"report.txt","mode": "add","autorename": true,"mute": false,"strict_conflict": false"}



     url := "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \" + ctoken
     cJSON := '{"c:\tmp\pdf\CKF1907319.pdf","mode": "add","autorename": true,"mute": false,"strict_conflict": false,}'
```

?   URL
?   cjson
wt = inkey(0)

```
oHTTP := CREATEOBJECT('Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0')
oHTTP:OPEN("POST",  url , .F.)
oHTTP:setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
oHTTP:SEND(cJSON)
    IF oHTTP:status != 200
    ? oHTTP:responseText
    hb_memowrit("response.txt",oHTTP:responseText)
    ? "Error"
ELSE
     ? oHTTP:responseText
     hb_memowrit("response.txt",oHTTP:responseText)
     ENDIF
     wt = inkey(0)
     return
```

Please help to solve this isssue

Thank You
Vikram

Comment: What language is this? JSCript .NET? It's easier for people to help if they browse by the correct tags. Also, it looks like you added your token to your example. A token should be considered a secret and should not be shared with other people.

Comment: @Vikram, if it was a security token you should disable it ASAP. It remains available in the history of this question. People will be able to abuse it

Comment: @Vikram I redacted it from your post, but you should [revoke](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#auth-token-revoke) that access token for your security.

Answer (score 0):

[ Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/Error-In-Uploading-a-file/td-p/410748 ]

The URL for the Dropbox API upload endpoint is just "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload". You appear to be adding your access token to the end of the URL, based on this line of code:

```
url := "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \" + ctoken
```

The access token should instead go in the "Authorization" header as a "Bearer" token, as shown in [the /2/files/upload documentation here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload).